# cvs2git was missing few commits during miration

Tags: cvs2git, git-fast-import

The few commits are missing while migrating from CVS to Git using cvs2git (Python 2.7.5). The missing commit messages are present in dumb.dat file but it doesn't imported into git.

Why the cvs2git missing commits while migrating from CVS to Git ?

```
cvs2git-tmp/git-dump.dat:Ref 06000 - <commit message> status in find route
cvs2git-tmp/git-dump.dat:Ref 06000 - <commit message> via implementation- removed unwanted code
cvs2git-tmp/git-dump.dat:Ref 06000 - <commit message> service startup file
```

Comment: Have you looked at the commits in question? Is there anything odd about them? Is their final content missing, or is it just somehow contained in another commit?

Comment: I'm not sure but my team getting the failure while compilation.

Comment: It is hard to help you if you yourself don't have a detailed description of the problem.

Comment: @Mort you are the person to help me a lot. Thank you so much and I am also in the process of migration. Kindly let me know, is there any possible, the jar getting corrupt while migration?